# Symbols loading VERY slow

Tags: c++, macos, gdb

I noticed recently that gdb takes a really long time before it starts executing code from my target application. I can't figure out why. I'm using MacOS 10.6.5 and GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1510)

If I interrupt it with CTRL-C, I can see the following output from backtrace (below). It looks like it's getting stuck loading symbols?

Anyway, I'm rather inexpert at how gdb works under the hood. Can someone suggest for me a tip to improve things?

```
#0  0x00007fff5fc05136 in __dyld__ZN4dyldL10loadPhase5EPKcRKNS_11LoadContextEPSt6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EE ()
#1  0x00007fff5fc0523f in __dyld__ZN4dyldL10loadPhase4EPKcRKNS_11LoadContextEPSt6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EE ()
#2  0x00007fff5fc0599e in __dyld__ZN4dyldL10loadPhase3EPKcRKNS_11LoadContextEPSt6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EE ()
#3  0x00007fff5fc05a47 in __dyld__ZN4dyldL10loadPhase1EPKcRKNS_11LoadContextEPSt6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EE ()
#4  0x00007fff5fc05b65 in __dyld__ZN4dyldL10loadPhase0EPKcRKNS_11LoadContextEPSt6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EE ()
#5  0x00007fff5fc05bf0 in __dyld__ZN4dyld4loadEPKcRKNS_11LoadContextE ()
#6  0x00007fff5fc06a5d in __dyld__ZN4dyldL14libraryLocatorEPKcbS1_PKN11ImageLoader10RPathChainE ()
#7  0x00007fff5fc0c746 in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader22recursiveLoadLibrariesERKNS_11LinkContextEbRKNS_10RPathChainE ()
#8  0x00007fff5fc0c66f in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader22recursiveLoadLibrariesERKNS_11LinkContextEbRKNS_10RPathChainE ()
#9  0x00007fff5fc0c66f in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader22recursiveLoadLibrariesERKNS_11LinkContextEbRKNS_10RPathChainE ()
#10 0x00007fff5fc0c7b6 in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader4linkERKNS_11LinkContextEbbRKNS_10RPathChainE ()
#11 0x00007fff5fc04d48 in __dyld__ZN4dyld4linkEP11ImageLoaderbRKNS0_10RPathChainE ()
#12 0x00007fff5fc068d6 in __dyld__ZN4dyld5_mainEPK12macho_headermiPPKcS5_S5_ ()
#13 0x00007fff5fc016d2 in __dyld__ZN13dyldbootstrap5startEPK12macho_headeriPPKcl ()
#14 0x00007fff5fc01052 in __dyld__dyld_start ()
```

Comment: Have you tried linking statically and comparing the results (GCC option `-static`)?

Comment: This won't solve it, but "man dyld" will give you some options.  Try setting the DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS environment variable to see where it spends its time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by repeatedly setting/restoring signal handlers in the gdb code. When I use

ptrace -p

I get pages of the matching system calls...

rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3bfc60f710}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {0x68a820, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK, 0x3bfc60f710}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3bfc60f710}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3bfc60f710}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {0x68a820, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK, 0x3bfc60f710}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3bfc60f710}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3bfc60f710}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {0x68a820, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK, 0x3bfc60f710}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3bfc60f710}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3bfc60f710}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {0x68a820, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK, 0x3bfc60f710}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3bfc60f710}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3bfc60f710}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {0x68a820, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK, 0x3bfc60f710}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3bfc60f710}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3bfc60f710}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {0x68a820, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK, 0x3bfc60f710}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3bfc60f710}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0